# How to make sure that my front-end Vue.js items cart is not outdated if a product that has already been added to it gets deleted from the back-end?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

I use localStorage to "remember" the items added to the cart. Whenever the application gets opened I check if a cart key-value exists in the localStorage like this:

```
let cartExists = localStorage.getItem('cart')
```

Then I set the cart to either empty array if cart doesn't exist in localStorage, or set it to the localStorage value

```
const cart = {
    state: {
        cart: cartExists ? JSON.parse(cartExists) : []
    },
}
```

When I add a product to the cart, I execute these 2 actions:

```
actions: {
    addCartItem(context, product){
        context.commit("ADD_CART_ITEM", product)
        context.dispatch("saveCartToLocalStorage")
    },
    saveCartToLocalStorage(context){
        localStorage.setItem('cart', JSON.stringify(context.state.cart))
    }
}
```

And finally I mutate the cart state by adding the product:

```
mutations: {
    ADD_CART_ITEM(state, product){
        let productInCart = state.cart.find(item => {
            return item.id === product.id
        })

        if (productInCart){
            Vue.set(productInCart, 'quantity', productInCart.quantity += 1);
        } else {
            Vue.set(product, 'quantity', 1);
            state.cart.push(product)
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that if I add a product to the cart, then delete that product from the back-end, the product still exists in the front-end cart and localStorage. I'm trying to figure out how to avoid that problem. Maybe make a GET request to check if the products still exist in the database before setting the cart state to the localStorage cart value?

Comment: It sounds like your backend determines whether or not a product should be deleted in the `ADD_CART_ITEM` action that presumably calls the backend endpoint, right? If it's something that happens in that call and not at a later time (like the product has expired, for example) then the answers will be different on how to handle that.